# Проблема с загрузкой шрифта sfml

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml

Недавно начал изучать sfml и возникла проблема при загрузке шрифта:

```
sf::Font font;
if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
    std::cout << "Font not loaded";
```

Шрифт не загружается, программа завершается с кодом -1073741819. Указывать полный путь пытался - ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я использовал sfml файлы для release версии, вместо debug

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать папку в рабочем каталоге, типа: 'font/arial.ttf' и загрузить туда сам шрифт. Далее задается данный шрифт тексту. Например:

```
// Instruction
    Font font;
    if (!font.loadFromFile("font/8277.ttf")) 
        return 0;
    Text text("F1 - New Game / Esc - Exit", font, 22);
    text.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    text.setPosition(5.f, 5.f);
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, при создании папки моё сообщение не печатается. Однако вылезает ошибка: Failed to load font и куча не понятных символов, программа завершается с тем же кодом